# Show related (archive) month and year to post

Tags: posts, post-meta

I want to show the related (archive) month and year for a post next to its contents, i.e. "Archived in January 2012". Any help / directions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code after the loop:

```
$month_num = get_the_date('n');
$month_txt = get_the_date('F');
$year = get_the_date('Y');

// change 'posts_per_page' to any value you need, '-1' means 'all'
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=-1&monthnum='.$month_num.'&year='.$year );

echo '<p class="">Archived in '.$month_txt.', '.$year.'</p>';
echo '<ul>';

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
endwhile;

echo '</ul>';
wp_reset_query();
```

It's not tested, but you got the idea.

Comment: Great, thanks guys! Wasn't familiar of get_the_date().

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_the_time()`, `get_month_link()` and `get_year_link()`:

```
function wpse_58787_archive_link()
{
    $Y   = get_the_time( 'Y' ); // year
    $m   = get_the_time( 'm' ); // month as number
    $F   = get_the_time( 'F' ); // month as word

    return 'Archived in <a href="' . get_month_link( $Y, $m ) . '">' . $F . '</a> 
    <a href="' . get_year_link( $Y ) . '">' . $Y . '</a>';
}

print wpse_58787_archive_link();
```